# Is $U(C(\beta \mathbb{D}))/U_0(C(\beta \mathbb{D}))\simeq K_1(C(\beta \mathbb{D}))$?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let

- $\mathbb{D}:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$,
- $\beta\mathbb{D}$ be the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{D}$,
- $C(\beta\mathbb{D})$ be the ring of complex-valued continuous functions on  $\beta\mathbb{D}$,
- $U(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))$ be the set of invertible elements in $C(\beta\mathbb{D})$,  and
- $U_0(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))$ be the connected component of 
  $U(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))$ that contains the identity element $1$.

**Question:**
Is $\omega: U(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))/U_0(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))\rightarrow  K_1(C(\beta\mathbb{D}))$ onto?